# Ideal in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

There is an ideal $(xy-1)$ in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ which belongs to $(x+1,y+1)$, so I want to know if there exists an ideal $I$: $(xy-1) \subset I \subset (x+1,y+1)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about the ideal 
$I=(x^2-1,x-y)$?

Comment: Is there a way how can we find all such ideals? Is it possible?

Comment: These ideals correspond to algebraic subsets in between $\{(1,1}\}$ and the hyperbola $y=1/x$. My $I$ corresponds to $\{(1,1),(-1,-1)\}$.